# RestSharp on Windows Phone 8 got no response

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone-8, restsharp

I tried to connect to my API using RestSharp. When I try with that code:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://api.com");
var request = new RestRequest("api/login", Method.POST);
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("login", "pass");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
 request.AddBody(new { customer = new { email = "email", password = "pass" } });
var response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
Console.ReadKey();
```

I got right response from server

But when it comes to Windows Phone 8

```
var client = new RestClient("http://api.com"); ;
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("login", "pass");
var request = new RestRequest("api/login", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");

request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(new { customer = new { email = "email", password = "pass" } });

 client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
{
    lblStatus.Text = response.Content ;
});
```

I got status code not found, server null. What did I do wrong?

Comment: *" I got status code not found"* where? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: I check it in watch when debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, that you must send request synchronyously. Just create class, that looks like this:

```
public static class RestClientExtensions
{
    public static Task<IRestResponse> ExecuteTask(this IRestClient client, RestRequest request)
    {
        var TaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();
        client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response, asyncHandle) =>
        {
            if (response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Error)
                TaskCompletionSource.SetException(response.ErrorException);
            else
                TaskCompletionSource.SetResult(response);
        });
        return TaskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

And now, you will be able to use it like this:

```
IRestResponse restResponse = await app.Client.ExecuteTask(request);
```

After this line you can easily get Content of response, just like you do it earlier:

```
lblStatus.Text = response.Content ;
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

in your code

```
var client = new RestClient(basicUrl);
client.ExecuteAsync<User>(request, (response) =>
        {
            user = response.Data;
        });
txtBox.Text = user.Name; //<---- its outside the Async event handler 
                        //so at this point user doesn't     
                        //have the info of the response
```

you need to change that line to inside the Async response method

Comment: but for instance I want do something like this.

`RestConnector rc = new RestConnector();
rc.executeLogin();
user = rc.user;`

My rc.user is null, how can I avoid it?

In executeLogin I got my code I posted above.